# Mechadendrites in dark heresy: sourcebooks and guidelines

Tags: warhammer-40k, dark-heresy-1e

**Short version:**
Besides the 5 mechadendrites in the core book "Dark Heresy", where can I find additional mechadendrites?
Does it exists any guidelines for house-ruling additional mechadendrites into game?

**Long version:**
In a on-going (first edition) Dark Heresy campaign I'm playing a tech-priest who, as most tech-priest do, want to mechanise themselves. My character happen to have a thing for mechadendrites, so I am planning ahead for the eventuality that the character lives to see the day all 5 mechadendrites in the sourcebook is attached and functional. Is there any rules for additional mechadendrites? Specific rules or guidelines and where I can find them is appreciated.

Our groups standing social rule is that we use official material first but house-rule things into existence if a suitable item does not exists (and the item fit the setting enough), so experiences with house-ruling mechadendrites is also welcome.

Comment: Are you playing first or second edition? First edition has a number of expansion source books (one of which is meant specifically for tech-priests), have you looked at them?

Comment: @xanderh We are playing first edition. I did not know there is an expansion for tech-priest specifically, what is it called? I do not have easy access to expansions, so I hoped people here with better knowledge (or easier access) would point me in the right direction.

Comment: The one for tech-priests is called "The Lathe Worlds".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a list of the Mechandendrites I am aware of.

Dark Heresy - DH01 - Core Rulebook (also Black Crusade /  Only War / Rogue Trader)

- Ballistic Mechadendrite
- Manipulator Mechadendrite
- Medicae Mechadendrite  (the Black Crusade Core Book calls them Medicae/Torture Mechadendrite !!!!)
- Optical Mechadendrite
- Utility Mechadendrite

Dark Heresy - DH11 - Ascension

- Plasma-cutter Mechadendrite

Black Crusade - BC07 - The Tome of Decay

- Mechatendril

Dark Heresy - DH18  - The Lathe Worlds

- Lathes Mechadendrite Stabilisers

You should also consider looking at the 5 Basic Mechadendrite in every Corebook (Black Crusade /  Only War / Rogue Trader / Dark Heresy) because they optimized them a lot. Therefore the newer books feel a little more balanced in regards to gear. (Deathwatch has no Mechadendrites.)

The only limit for the number of Mechadendrites is your Toughness bonus.

Comment: Thank you! Follow-up question: what does "powerplaning" mean in this context? Tried searching the site but your answer is the only place it occurs.